# Is this houseplant with flowers that have pink petals and a yellow center, and reddish stems, an impatiens?

Tags: identification, houseplants, flowers

My wife is trying to identify this flowering plant and thinks it's an impatiens, but the number of visible petals (4), and the yellow bit in the middle, makes me feel that's not quite right.

What do you think?

Click on these pictures to see larger versions. They're also available in my [online album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp6im.jpg).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not an impatiens - they would show five petals or more.

What we are looking at here is a [begonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begonia).

Tell-tale characteristics are:

- Asymmetrical leaves.
- The pattern of four petals with two larger ones and two smaller ones across.
- Thick waxy stems with somewhat bamboo-ish joints.

Your plants look a bit worse for wear, so I'm hesitant to give a detailed id.

Comment: Thank you! I'll let her know she needs to help it get into better health!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are Begonia, and are struggling for light, hack them back savagely and put them in warm, filtered light, or morning sun pozzie & water regularly. They will love you long time.